# C# How to read an value from xml tag (xmlnodelist) using their attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnodelist

Could you helping me to know how get the value of xml tag using their attribute with C#.
need:

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je91w.png)

```
<Friend>
   <FName>Patrick</FName>
   <LName>Aston</LName>
   <Age>22</Age>
   <FriendsIdList>
       <FriendId IdType="school">29982252</FriendId>
       <FriendId IdType="athome">2334568</FriendId>
       <FriendId IdType="atcamp">9908787</FriendId>
       <FriendId IdType="studygroup">6588432</FriendId>
   </FriendsIdList>
</Friend>
```

How to get the value of tag    `<FriendId IdType="XXXXX">XXXXXX</FriendId>`    I was try using XMLnodelist into an foreach sequence, but without success.
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated this post. Thanks

Comment: Use `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`.

Comment: Hi Nyerguds, my code it is so fool, does not works as I wanted. it is simple foreach over the elements of XMLnodelist, and inside the foreach I put some silly "if" sequences, with contains or equals instructions. But these doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq using a dictionary to get Ids

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication51
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Friend").Select(x => new {
                fName = (string)x.Element("FName"),
                lName = (string)x.Element("LName"),
                age = (int)x.Element("Age"),
                ids = x.Descendants("FriendId")
                   .GroupBy(y => (string)y.Attribute("IdType"), z => (string)z)
                   .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())
            }).ToList();



        }
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks jdweng, Then with ids, I will find these elements? i'm right?

Comment: I added a screen image of results.